# Getting json array value from the AJAX call in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an AJAX call and I can see in my console that I am getting this JSON:

```
{
 "status": 400,
 "code": 11,
 "property": "validation",
 "errorMessages": [
    {
        "type": "m",
        "name": "2",
        "description": "The value must be less than or equal to 10"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was trying to get the values of errorMessage like this but no luck:

```
    console.log(data.errorMessages[0].description);
```

where data is the JSON object.

How can I get this description value?

Comment: [That should work](http://jsfiddle.net/RDHs3/), do you parse the JSON?

Comment: have you tried logging only `data`?

Comment: console.log(data); gives me [object Object]

Comment: how do you receive that JSON object btw?

Comment: In the firebug, I get this JSON as a server response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
opt = {
 "status": 400,
 "code": 11,
 "property": "validation",
 "errorMessages": [
    {
        "type": "m",
        "name": "2",
        "description": "The value must be less than or equal to 10"
    }
  ]
}

console.log(opt.errorMessages[0].description);
```

Here's is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uj3UE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are missing is [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) or you can put `dataType: 'json'` in your `ajaxSetup` to do it automatically (i.e. convert well-formed JSON string to JavaScript object). You can add `dataType: 'json'` only for this specific AJAX call of course.
For example:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: <your URL>,
            data: <your input>,
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
     });
```

Also make sure that the server from which you are getting response, sends correct MIME type in the header, i.e. `'Content-Type: application/json'`